# Mvc Dropdownlist Select picker not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am quite sure it may be some script reference i need, but heres what i have so far.

My Scripts:

```
    script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true,
            showSubtext: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

using Knockout after this to load in objects.

My Css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

and the normal Bootstrap.

here is my dropdown:

```
 <td><u>persons</u><br />@Html.DropDownList("PersonId", (SelectList)ViewBag.PersonId, "Choose the person you want.", htmlAttributes: new
                           {
                               @class = "selectpicker",
                               data_show_subtext = "true",
                               data_live_search = "true"
                           })
```

if i inspect the page, i can find the select with the correct options, but not showing on page unless i remove the class "Selectpicker" any advice how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check on chrome developers tools what are the computed attributes for this element, you might find out that there is another implementation for this class that hides it.

to see the computed attributes:

1. Open developer tools on google chrome (f12 or inspect element on the desired element)
2. Select the element you want to check on the Elements Tab
3. From the right pane of the developer tools select the Computed Tab

there you will find the list of computed CSS attributes and if you click on any of the attributes it'll open the location of this implementation

hope that will help

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but i haven't been able to find the error.

Comment: Funny thing is i have exact same code, on other page. Same layout and everything. and it works there. I think it may be something to do with the Knockout

Comment: Oka, i have found the Error. It's because it's inside a  script text/html tag. Once i moved it out it worked. But i need it to be inside there. So have to find a solution for this.

Comment: why do you have to leave it there? "text/html" scripts are templates and wont get rendered  by the page

Comment: Because i use the template when creating new, or editing my objects. How else would you suggest i did it, ?

Comment: You can create custom HTML Helpers for razor that extends the DropDownList Helper's functionality, then you can encapsulate the template string from within the helper's code
Please read the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Thanks alot, i will take a look. ;)

Comment: hmm, couldn't i use the javascript :"$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true,
            showSubtext: true
        });": when it's being rendered? so instead of having it on document load? Sorry, if this is a silly question..

Comment: Yes you can, because HTML helpers renders the HTML as String (which you can see and manipulate in C#) then just pastes in the DOM

document.ready sure runs after that step is completed :D

Comment: hmm, tried adding it to my buttoms click (it's getting called once i click on "create". Sadly same issue, But asfar as i understand Razor, it Reads the c# code first and then the javascript /html? If so i wouldn't be able to use the Html helper this way? Or maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Kinda silly i don't have enough reputation to move it to a chat.

Comment: No, you can use HTML Helpers to parse the template for you, but you can keep the javascript code in the page, this way given the execution order you gave it should work fine

Comment: hmm i was more thinking something like getting a javascript function and add it to the template onload="fucntion()" ??

Comment: Added alot more code on here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589393/using-selectpicker-with-knockout Since i closed this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, the following code was not rendering:

`<div class="field">
     <label for="title">Title</label>
          @Html.DropDownList("TitleList", new SelectList(Model.claimantTitles, "TitleId", "Title"), "--Select Title--", new { @class = "dropdown-menu", @arialabelledby = "dropdownlabel" })
 </div>`

I removed: `@class = "dropdown-menu"` and it worked